# to access a specific key-value pair in hash

Tags: perl, hash

I want to print only the specific key:pair from the following hash in perl:

```
1: one
2: two
3: three
```

and I am using the following statement to print my hash:

```
foreach (sort keys %hash) {
    print "$_ : $hash{$_}";
 }
```

what should the code if I only want to print `1: one` or `2: two` from the hash.

Comment: How about `print "1: $hash{1}";`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
foreach (sort keys %hash) {
  if ($_ eq 1 ) {
    print "$_ : $hash{$_}";
    last;
  }
}
```

Using `last` will cause your loop to exit as soon as condition is met. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This is ***wrong***. There is no need to search through all the hash keys to find a match: just `print "1 : $hash{1}"` will do fine. And *all* hash keys are strings and should *always* be compared using `eq`

Answer (score 2):

A hash is designed to enable fast lookup of a value for a given key. You would only `foreach` through all keys of your hash if you wanted to see or do something to every single value. If you wanted to just look up the value for a given key, you would, as mentioned by [Сухой27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B927) and [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin), use

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    1 => "one",
    2 => "two",
    3 => "three",
);

print "1: $hash{1}\n";
print "2: $hash{2}\n";
```

or, more general for a key `$key`:

```
print "$key: $hash{$key}\n";
```